# What is the expected value and standard deviation of the total cost of the meal?

Tags: probability

The expected value and variance of the cost of appetizers as a
certain restaurant is \$5.04 and 0.6484, respectively. In addition to the appetizer, a drink is
ordered that is \$2. A sales tax of 7% is added to the cost of all of the meals. What is the expected value and standard deviation of the total cost of the meal?

I was thinking of writing a function of the cost of meal like $g(x)=(\$5.04x+\$2y)\cdot 1.07$. But that doesn't seem right?

Comment: Let $X$ be a random variable whole value is the cost of the meal and appetizer.  The total bill comes to $g(X)= 1.07(X+2)$

Comment: Then the $Var(g(X))=1.07^2\cdot Var(X)$?

Comment: That's correct.